# How to structure the code to process multiple variables from mulitple form elements in JavaScript and remember the choices?

Tags: javascript, ajax, design-patterns, optimization, architecture

E.g. I have an HTML form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="" >

    <!-- DIRECT SEARCH INPUT TO SEARCH STRING -->
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" /> 
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />

    <!-- DROPDOWN TO SELECT ONE CHOICE -->
    <select name='country' id='country' class='postform' >
        <option class="level-0" value="2">USA</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="3">Canada</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="4">Mexico</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="5">Cuba</option>
    </select>

    <!-- CHECKBOXES TO SELECT MULTIPLE CHOICES -->
    <div id="color">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="21" />Beachfront
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="16" />TV
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="20" />Internet
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="17" />Pets Allowed
    </div> 

</form>

<div id="results"><!-- THE AJAX RESULTS GOES HERE --></div>
```

And I want to be able to make AJAX request every time the user:

**1) write something in the search input box and click search button**

OR

**2) select one choice from the dropdown menu**

OR

**3) select one or multiple choices from the checkboxes that are checked**

The problem is that I don't know how to structure my JavaScript code correctly and what is the best way to remember and manage choices that the user selected before, to take all things in account. For example, not just the search term when he write something and click search button, but also to take in count the dropdown choice (probably done one step before) and maybe the checked options from checkboxes if he has checked something before. Here is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // RESULTS SHOULD APPEAR IN #results DIV AFTER AJAX IS DONE
    var $maincontent = $('#results'); 



    // SEARCH INPUT PROCESSING
    $('#searchsubmit').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();

        var searchval = $('#s').val();

        $.post(
            WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action : 'ajax_search_action_do',
                searchval : searchval
            },
            function( response ) {
                $maincontent.empty();
                $maincontent.append( response );
            }
        );
    });

    // COUNTRY DROPDOWN CHOICE PROCESSING
    $('#country').on('change', function() { 

            var countryval = this.value;

            $maincontent.animate({ opacity : '0.1' })

            $.post(
                WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
                {
                    action : 'ajax_search_action_do',
                    countryval : countryval
                },
                function( response ) {
                    $maincontent.empty();
                    $maincontent.append( response );
                    $maincontent.animate({ opacity : '1' })
                }
            );

            return false;
    });


    // CHECKBOXES PROCESSING
    $('#color input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {    
        if (this.checked) {
            // code if checked
        }
        else {
            // nothing
        }        

    });

});
```

As you can see, it's very bad. Because one "function" checks only click, one change and I don't know how to grab values from the checkboxes and make an array and send it via ajax ;(.

Any idea how to structure the JavaScript code so it is not so separated and the checks are somehow in one part (or more logical) instead of three separated parts?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Create som logic :

```
var _do = {
    bind: function() {
        var self = this;
        $('#searchsubmit').on('click', function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            self.ajax('searchval', $('#s').val());
        });

        $('#country').on('change', function() { 
            self.ajax('countryval', this.value);
        });
        return self;
    },
    ajax: function(key, value) {
        var data = {action: 'ajax_search_action_do'};
        data[key] = value;
        $.post(
            WPaAjax.ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
                $maincontent.empty().append( response );
            }
        );
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    _do.bind();
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks it looks clean and it's easy to read ;). I will try it and let you know.

Comment: It's just a general example, and will probably need some fine tuning.

Comment: One question. Could it be possible to catch the value of `countryval` in the "destination" function `ajax_search_action_do` using `$country = $_POST['countryval'];` like I have done it with my old code?

Comment: And could I ask what is `bind:` Is it from jquery or javascript? Could you post a link where to read more about this feature. It seems to be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use jquery.form.js?
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

It's a great plugin, just structure the form like it was a normal redirection form, add array in name of checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="21" />Beachfront
```

Add target URL to the form, and then...

When u want to submit the form just do

```
$('searchform').ajaxSubmit({

  success: function() {

    // callback

  }

)
```

Trigger this on checkboxes change, dropdown change etc. To make the code clean, use one selector

```
$('#country, #s, #color input').on('change', sendAjaxForm);
```

Comment: Will it remember the choices made before?

Comment: I am building it using WordPress ajax so I would preffer some solution without this plugin and just general jQuery and JavaScript if possible.

Comment: You should just make one function for sending the form, that will analyze it's structure (check checkboxes for $(element).is(':checked') ) and trigger it on changes. "Choices" will stay the same as you are not changing anything in the DOM of form upon submitting

Comment: I am using this plugin with wordpress all the time, there's no hassle ;), just use WP's AJAX url and add 'action' key to the form in the hidden input or before ajax submitting

Comment: Hmm, I am looking at it now and seems interesting. Have you done with this plugin some "advanced" search things in WordPress?

Comment: I've done some crazy stuff with it, not just searches ;) It is simple enough to use it in variety of scenarios, I honestly recommend this plugin